# How to build from source on CentOS 5.9?

Tags: centos, yum, centos5, rpm

I'm building [iptraf-ng](https://fedorahosted.org/iptraf-ng/wiki/Download) on CentOS 5.9 and running into the following errors:

```
src/packet.c: In function ‘packet_process’:
src/packet.c:322: error: ‘ETH_P_QINQ1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/packet.c:322: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/packet.c:322: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/packet.c:323: error: ‘ETH_P_QINQ2’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/packet.c:324: error: ‘ETH_P_QINQ3’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/packet.c:325: error: ‘ETH_P_8021AD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I am assuming that this is from the build not seeing the kernel or network interface constant definitions properly.  This is on a virtual machine and the normal version of straight `iptraf` will not work with vnet0.

What would be the proper steps to include the support libraries here for compilation?

NOTE: I have also attempted to build the [source rpm](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-x86_64/iptraf-ng-1.1.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) as well, however it's a losing battle it seems as per [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=499385).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've either not installed the kernel headers, or these symbols have been introduced in kernel version 2.6.19 or newer. In the latter case you're out of luck and should upgrade to centos 6.

Comment: CentOS uses 2.6.18 (missed it by that much!) and I've verified kernel-headers-2.6.18-348.el5 does not contain include files with `ETH_P_QINQ1`.